# Is there any way to auto run all my Unit Tests before archiving release build in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, development-environment

How do I automatically perform unit tests before archiving build in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the continuous integration on locally on your computer adding by its steps. There are variety options are available. `fastlane` or `bitrise` (I use bitrise to build easy steps). For `bitrise`, more information could be found this link (https://app.bitrise.io/cli) By doing this you can achieve the steps that you want to do with your build process.